# Maintaining the particular special character/s after/before a word while doing re.sub in Python

Tags: python, regex, re-python

I am trying to replace a word using re.sub in python. The format is

`re.sub(pattern, replacement,string)`

Lets consider the following snippet of code

`sentence = "I want to replce this sentence"`

`pattern = "replce"`

`replacement = "replace"`

`print(re.sub("[\W]{}[\W]".format(pattern), " {} ".format(replacement), sentence))`

Would give output

**I want to replace this sentence**

Now I want to capture the non-alphanumeric characters around the pattern so that I can include them in the replacement as well. In this example, I am forcing spaces around replacement, which should not be the scenario.

For example

`sentence = "I want to !replce, this sentence"`

`pattern = "replce"`

`replacement = "replace"`

`print(re.sub("[\W]{}[\W]".format(pattern), " {} ".format(replacement), sentence))`

Would give output

**I want to replace this sentence**

but I want

**I want to !replace, this sentence**

What is the solution?

Comment: Use word boundaries, `\b`. Or `(?<!\w){}(?!\w)`

Comment: Did not work, can you give me the whole expression so that I can check if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: https://ideone.com/qZphcN

Comment: Thanks, that worked.